# Hi, my IF code is coming up as false. I am trying to convert survey answers to numbers to run analysis

Tags: excel

```
=IF($D2="5 (Somewhat agree)",5,IF($D2="1 (Strongly disagree)",1,IF($D2="2 (Disagree)",2,IF($D2="3 (Somewhat disagree)",3,IF($D2="4 (Neither agree nor disagree)",4,IF($D2="6 (Agree)",6,IF($D2="7 (Strongly Agree)",7,IF($D2="","NA"))))))))
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my machine

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your values always start with the number of interest so you can just use `LEFT` to extract the number. The exception is the blank inputs that output  . You can control the output here with a single `IF` to convert   to `NA`

```
=LEFT(D2, 1)
```

---

You can also use `VLOOKUP` to import your values. Just create a reference table (*see table on left below*) and then reference it to output the appropriate mapping. For blanks this will return `#N/A` although you can control the error output by wrapping this in `IFERROR`

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,A2:$B$7,2,0)
```

---

[image]